# How to solve $\ln[e^{x}+e^{y}]=px+(1-p)y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $p$ be a real number. I am looking for all $(x,y)$ such that $\ln[e^{x}+e^{y}]=px+(1-p)y$. My effort:

Take exponent of both sides to obtain $e^{x}+e^{y}=e^{px}e^{(1-p)y}$ and then let $X=e^{x}, Y=e^{y}$, so that $X+Y=X^{p}Y^{1-p}$.  How can I proceed from here?

Comment: Solving for $x$ or $y$?

Comment: for $(x,y)$.  Will edit the question.

Comment: Have you get concrete values for $p$?

Comment: I would settle for rational $p$, $0 \leq p \leq1$

Comment: I think that gives the Heinz inequality

Comment: @attepl, what is the Heinz inequality?\

Comment: See wikipedia here : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinz_mean

Comment: @attepl, I looked it up, but connection is unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do some fantasy trick. Let's call $y = \alpha x$. No problem in doing that, there will always exist an $\alpha$ such that $x = \alpha y$. Hence:

$$\ln(e^x + e^{\alpha x}) = px + \alpha x - \alpha p x$$

$$\ln(e^x + e^{\alpha x}) =  p(1-\alpha)x + \alpha x$$

Exponentiating

$$e^x + e^{\alpha x} = e^{p(1-\alpha)x}e^{\alpha x}$$

$$e^x = e^{\alpha x}\left(e^{p(1-\alpha)x} - 1\right)$$

$$e^{x - \alpha x} + 1 = e^{p(1-\alpha)x}$$

$$p(1-\alpha) x = \ln(e^{x-\alpha x} + 1)$$

$$p = \frac{\ln(e^{x-\alpha x} + 1)}{(1-\alpha)x}$$

$$p = \frac{\ln(e^{x- y} + 1)}{x-y}$$

And we of course need to have $x \neq y$, which is rather good since for $x = y$ we would get at the beginning $\ln(2) = 0$.

Comment: @ Von Neumann, how do I find $(x,y)$ from here?

Comment: @ZviadKhukhunashvili Your $(x, y)$ are all the possible real values, with $x \neq y$. For each value of $x$ and $y$ you will get a unique value of $p$ and vice versa. Also, you notice that you have not domains problems in the numerator since it does exist for any value. The attentions lays on the denominator.

Comment: would it be different if $x,y$ were assumed to be complex numbers?

Comment: @ZviadKhukhunashvili That would need more attention when dealing with the logarithms and the real/imaginary parts. I will think better later!

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to Von Neumanns answer I took $y=kx$ which eventually gave
$$e^x+e^{kx}=e^{px+kx-pkx}$$
then letting $t=e^x$ gives
$$t+t^k=t^{p+k-pk}$$
$$1+t^{k-1}=t^{p+k-pk-1}=t^{(k-1)(1-p)}$$
$$t^{(k-1)(1-p)}-t^{k-1}-1=0$$
finally substituting $s=t^{k-1}$ gives the equation
$$s^{1-p}-s-1=0$$
Solving this equation however one deems necessary gives the solution
$$y=x+\ln{(s_0)}$$
for the positive root $s_0$ which only exists for $p\lt 0$ or $p\ge1$. This solution results from reversing the substitution
$$s=t^{k-1}=e^{x(k-1)}=e^{xk-x}=e^{y-x}$$
$$\therefore e^y=se^x \implies y=x+\ln{(s)}$$

Comment: does the solution set of the $(x,y)$ have a special name from algebraic geometry?

Comment: @PeterForman, how do you solve $$s^{1-p}-s-1=0$$ for $s$ ?

Comment: Numerical methods would have to be used unless $p=\pm1,\pm2, \pm3$ in which case the quadratic, cubic and quartic formulae can be used.

Answer (score 1):

When $p\notin [0,1]$, one can proceed as in the other answers to obtain solutions and your set will be just a line parallel to the vector $(1,1)$. However, since it was expressed in the comments that the case of interest was $p\in [0,1]$, I will focus in that case.

Note that whenever $\ln(e^x+e^y)=px+(1-p)y$ for some $p\in [0,1]$, we have that
$$
\ln(e^x+e^y)\in [x,y].
$$
However,
$$
\ln(e^x+e^y)\geq \ln(2e^{\max\{x,y\}})=\ln(2)+\max\{x,y\}>\max\{x,y\}
$$
and therefore $\ln(e^x+e^y)$ cannot lie in the interval $[x,y]$, because it is bigger than any number in that interval.

In conclusion, the set
$$
\{(x,y)\mid \ln(e^x+e^y)=px+(1-p)y\}
$$
is empty for $p\in [0,1]$.

Comment: would it make a difference if $x,y$ were complex numbers?